Difference between Soumya and Ugra deities.?
Some Hindu deities are Soumya like Ganapathi, Saraswati, Krishna  but some are very Ugra like Kali, Chinnamasta, Narasimha . What is the significant difference between Soumya and Ugra deities. What is the purpose of Soumya deities and what is the purpose of Ugra deities? Is there any difference between their capabilities? Thank you.

The Neela-Lohita or Krishna-Pinglam are the words use to signify the Ardhanarishwara form of Bhagawan Shiva and Mata Parvati which implies the Agni-Soma nature of the Universe. With Neela (Maya/Prakriti), he envelops with maya and with Lohita (Ishwara/Purusha), he impales thus gives moksha (sometimes also by killing them).

Rudra is the embodiment of all Devas. All devas are merely different manifestations (parts) of Sri Rudra Himself. On the right side of Rudra, there is the sun, then the four-headed Brahma, and then three Agnis (fires). On the left side, there exist Sri Umadevi, and also Vishnu and Soma (moon). (Rudra hridhaya upanishad).
Uma Herself is the form of Vishnu. Vishnu Himself is the form of the moon. Therefore, those who worship Lord Vishnu, worship Lord Siva Himself. And those who worship Lord Siva, worship Lord Vishnu. Those who envy and hate Sri Rudra, are actually hating Sri Vishnu. Those who decry Lord Siva, decry Lord Vishnu Himself. (Rudra hridhaya upanishad).
Rudra is the generator of the seed. Vishnu is the embryo of the seed. Siva Himself is Brahma and Brahma Himself is Agni. Rudra is full of Brahma and Vishnu. The whole world is full of Agni and Soma. The masculine gender is Lord Siva. The feminine gender is Sri Bhavani Devi. All the mobile and immobile creation of this universe, is filled up with Uma and Rudra. The Vyakta is Sri Uma, and the Avyakta is Lord Siva. (Rudra hridaya upanishad).

MBH Anusashana Parva, SECTION CLXI.:

"Vasudeva said, '. . . Brahmanas conversant with the Vedas say that that god has two forms. One of these is terrible, and the other mild and auspicious. Those two forms, again, are subdivided into many forms. That form which is fierce and terrible is regarded as identical with Agni and Lightning and Surya. The other form which is mild and auspicious is identical with Righteousness and water and Chandramas. Then, again, it is said that half his body is fire and half is Soma (or the moon). . .'

So, Purusha (Agni) Forms are Ugra and Prakriti (Soma) forms are Saumya. Both gives liberation just one like Agni burns and makes you pure and other like Soma through amrita makes you pure. Same as Father and Mother. Father is strict and Mother is caring. But ultimately both loves you and make you successful in their own ways.
I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..

Thank you for the answer , but if I do the sadhana of ugra deity then sooner or later I will have some experience which might be terrifying, but if I worship Soumya delta then I will have some pleasant experience . Then what the purpose of such experience. When should I look for terrifying experience and when should I look for pleasant experiences? Thank you.

It's not just black and white terrifying or pleasant. It's grey. Like in Cold whether fire/sun gives you warmth and in Hot weather water/ice gives you refreshment. So, both are necessary. The entire universe is made of Agni and Soma. Mother and Father both are necessary. That's why Shiva-Shakti are said to be one as Ardhanarishwara. And you are Welcome. ..
